# Gradle stuck at debugCompile

Tags: android, build, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to build my Android project, (with android studio and also from command prompt) It gets stuck while building on this line

[image]

Here is build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 20 
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:twowayview:0.1.4'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.0@aar'
    compile 'uk.co.androidalliance:edgeeffectoverride:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.fernandodev.easyratingdialog:easyratingdialog:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.github.flavienlaurent:datetimepicker:0f5d399995'
    compile 'com.roomorama:caldroid:2.0.0'
}
```

I was using newest version of android studio from canary channel (I think it was version 1.4 RC, and I tried to downgrade to stable version but problem persisted) Also I tried running build/cmd as admin but it did not help.

Anyone seems to know what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I restarted PC, and let it run for half an hour. Now it works both from Android studio and console.